# Are Kivy Layouts Essentially Widgets?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy app that I am (learning) to write. I am a bit confused about the layouts and when to use which ones.

I have a base class  in a .kv file that then contains a number of layouts. Eventually these components will talk to each other and will be dynamically generated, but the first thing I wanted to do was just to get all the components on a screen to see if I could.

In a structure like this:

```
<MyApp>
    <AnchorLayout>
        <Widget1>
        <Widget2>
    <FloatLayout>
        <Widget3>
        <Widget4>
    <Label>
        text: "text here"
```

where is the proper place to use the `size_hint` and `pos_hint` tags. Should it be at the widget level, or the layout level? If anyone can be bothered, the reason I am asking this is that in the following code, it seems that for the Label at the end, I have to position it manually, the pos_hint does nothing (I want it more or less 25% up the page on the left hand side). What am I missing?

[image]

```
# File name: MagStripeApp.kv
#:kivy 1.9.0

<MagStripeReader>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        HeaderBar:
            id: _header_bar
            size_hint: 1, 0.15
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        SessionBar:
            id: _session_bar
            mag_stripe_reader: root
            entry_box: _entry_box
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        EntryBox:
            id: _entry_box
            request_box: _request_box
            person_counter: _person_counter
            request_box: _request_box
            size_hint: 0.333, 1
        RequestBox:
            id: _request_box
            person_counter: _person_counter
            card_reader: _card_reader
            size_hint: 0.333, 1
        CardReader:
            id: _card_reader
            person_counter: _person_counter
            size_hint: 0.333, 1
        PersonCounter:
            id: _person_counter


<HeaderBar@Label>:
    text: "Mag Stripe Reader Application"
    font_size: root.height/2.5
    size: self.texture_size
    bold: True
    color: 0, 0.70, 0.93, 1

    #This is not quite right, but is ok for now. The resizing does not work 
    #quite perfectly. 

<SessionButton@ToggleButton>:
    group: 'session_options' 
    background_color: 0, 0.70, 0.93, 1
    color: 0.11, 0.39, 0.33, 0.75, 0.02
    bold: True

<SessionBar@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    #col_default_width: root.width/3
    SessionButton:
        text: "Start Session"
    SessionButton:
        text: "End Session"

<EntryButton@Button>:
    group: 'entry_buttons'
    background_color: 0, 0.70, 0.93, 1
    color: 0.11, 0.39, 0.33, 0.75, 0.02
    bold: True

<EntryBox@GridLayout>:
    pos_hint: {'x':0, 'center_y':0.5}
    cols: 1
    rows: 2
    Label: 
        text: "Does Entrant have an EBT card?"
        font_size: root.height/8
        size: self.texture_size
        bold: True
        color: 0, 0.70, 0.93, 1
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        EntryButton:
            text: 'YES'
        EntryButton: 
            text: 'NO'

<RequestButton@Button>:
    group: 'request_buttons'
    background_color: 0, 0.70, 0.93, 1
    color: 0.11, 0.39, 0.33, 0.75, 0.02
    bold: True

<RequestBox@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    rows: 2
    pos_hint: {'x': 0.333, 'center_y':0.5}
    Label: 
        text: "Will Entrant scan EBT card?"
        font_size: root.height/8
        size: self.texture_size
        bold: True
        color: 0, 0.70, 0.93, 1
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        EntryButton:
            text: 'YES'
        EntryButton: 
            text: 'NO'

<CardReader@GridLayout>
    cols: 1
    rows: 2
    pos_hint: {'x': 0.666, 'center_y':0.5}
    Label:
        text: 'Please scan EBT card'
        font_size: root.height/8
        size: self.texture_size
        bold: True
        color: 0, 0.70, 0.93, 1
    TextInput:
        password: True
        multiline: False

<PersonCounter@Label>:
    id: _person_counter
    text: '1'
    pos_hint: {'x' : 0.1, 'y' : 0.25}
    #pos: -500, 100
    size: self.texture_size
    halign: 'left'
    font_size: 50
```

Answer (score 3):

> Are Kivy Layouts Essentially Widgets?

Layouts *are* widgets. The declaration of the Layout class is `class Layout(Widget):` etc.

> where is the proper place to use the size_hint and pos_hint tags. Should it be at the widget level, or the layout level?

It should be one level below whatever widget you're trying to set their value for. e.g.

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'  # this applies to the BoxLayout instance
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.75  # The FloatLayout will take 75% of the vertical space
        Label:
            pos_hint: {x: '0.5', y: '0.75'}  # The Label is placed 50% across the x axis, and 75% up the y axis
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 50, 50  # ...and has a fixed size
            text: '!'
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.25
```

I can't comment on your specific example with a Label, because it's not valid kv and doesn't try to do the thing you says fails. If this doesn't answer things for you, provide a full example that doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I am sure that my code is not valid kv, but how not? Right at the end I try to subclass label and pass `pos_hint: {'x' : 0.1, 'y' : 0.25}` which to me, should place the label 10% across the x and 25% up the Y, but as you can see from the screen shot, the text '1' just ends up sort of in the middle. That is what I am not understanding.